# Why doesn't my fav icon work in Chrome any more?

Tags: html, google-chrome, firefox, web, cross-browser

My favicon worked on [Chrome Canary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Chrome#Release_channels_and_updates) for a while, and after I updated it it stopped appearing.

I have provided my code below.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
        <title>Write IT</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried emptying your cache?

Comment: yes and clearing all other info as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct MIME-type for .ico files is `image/vnd.microsoft.icon`. Since `image/x-icon` is not standardized it's most often a leniency of a browser not checking for it if it actually works.