# Website Icon Not Showing Up in Google Chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, favicon

I've visited these questions and none of the answers worked for me:

[Why doesn't my fav icon work in Chrome any more?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16020179/why-doesnt-my-fav-icon-work-in-chrome-any-more)

[Chrome doesn't show the favicon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16869112/chrome-doesnt-show-the-favicon)

---

### My Code

My website is http://mikeyaworski.com and this is the code I use to set my icon:

```
<head>
    <title>mikeyaworski</title>
    <link 
          rel="shortcut icon" 
          href="http://mikeyaworski.com/myicon.ico" 
          type="image/vnd.microsoft.icon" 
    >   
</head>
```

This is my [entire code](http://pastie.org/8658550).

### What I've Tried

- Instead of `rel="shortcut icon"`I've tried `rel="icon"`
- Instead of `type="image/vnd.microsoft.icon"` I've tried `type="image/x-icon"`
- Instead of `href="http://mikeyaworski.com/myicon.ico"` I've tried `href="myicon.ico"`

---

The icon works in Mozilla and Internet Explorer. The icon does not work in Google Chrome. Any ideas?

Comment: You can just use `favicon.png` (or ico) in the root directory, you don't even need any markup.

Comment: @RadGH I have it in the root directory (http://mikeyaworski.com/myicon.ico) but any other pages on my site (http://mikeyaworski.com/about.html) don't use the icon, assumingly because they don't have the markup.

Comment: Use the name `favicon.ico`, the filename is important there ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your html is invalid and your browser tries to *fix* it. In doing so your link tag ends up outside the head and is ignored, fix your html and it will work

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>mikeyaworski</title>
    <link rel="icon" href="myicon.ico" type="image/vnd.microsoft.icon">

  </head>
  <body>    <!-- body tag should be here -->
    <h1 style="text-align:center;font-family:trebuchet ms;" id="top"><br><br>Hompage</h1>
    <p>
    Coming soon. Until then, view my <a href="http://stackoverflow.com">StackOverflow</a> and other StackExchange profiles:
    </p>

    <a href="http://stackexchange.com/users/2644958">
      <img src="http://stackexchange.com/users/flair/2644958.png?theme=dark" width="208" height="58" alt="profile for mike yaworski on Stack Exchange, a network of free, community-driven Q&A sites" title="profile for mike yaworski on Stack Exchange, a network of free, community-driven Q&A sites">
    </a>


  <body>
</html>
<!-- <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon"> -->
```

Comment: Specifically the `<body>` tag in the website comes before the `<head>` tag, which was fixed in Musa's code. That's the main issue. The whitespace / indentation / etc is not important to the browser (In most cases, anyway, never have white space above the doctype!).

Answer (score 1):

Try using the following code:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
```

Or Else have a go at the link below with similar discussion:

[local (file://) website favicon works in Firefox, not in Chrome or Safari- why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11221292/local-file-website-favicon-works-in-firefox-not-in-chrome-or-safari-why)

Update:
Or else give a following link a try:
  [Fix missing favicons on Google Chrome](http://www.techspot.com/community/topics/fix-missing-favicons-on-google-chrome.194699/)

Hope this helps.
Thanks,
Jatin